# how to get data in back (.cs file) the way as easy we get it in front(.razor component) with @inject

Tags: c#, database, blazor-server-side, inject

i coded a good way to get data on the front side on razor components like i injected

```
@inject IPeopleData _dbpeople
```

[image: PeopleData]

refering to SQLDataAccess here:

[image: SQLDataAccess]

so i get data like this

```
private List<PersonModel> people;
people = await _dbpeople.GetPeople();
```

and it worked well !!

but when i tried to get data from Peoplegenerator.cs file impossible...

how to do in the same way like an @inject ..? or do we necesserly have to do another way ..?

Answer (score 0):

From a component you can call a few different methods to work with the injected service.

Depending on your use case you should either override `OnInitializedAsync` or `OnParametersSetAsync` or `OnAfterRenderAsync`

Keep in mind that async streaming or using the `OnAfterRenderAsync` requires you to call `StateHaseChanged` afterwards

Comment: thanks but i dont want from component but from cs file ...
cant find a way to make it work from my cs file in blazor serverside environment

Comment: You can create a partial class. For example if your file name is MyComponent.razor you can add a class named MyComponent.razor.cs make it partial and then you can override the events in the cs file.